# How do I end this do while loop?

Tags: c++, loops, conditional-statements, do-while

This is probably a very newbie question but I am just practising classes for C++ and cannot seem to get this do while loop to end under a boolean condition.

```
int main()
{
    bool endgame = false;
    string x;
    int choice;
    cout << "please choose the colour you want your bow to be:\n";
    cin >> x;
    Bow bow1(x);
    do
    {
        cout << "please choose what you would like to do\n";
        cout << "(1 draw bow\n(2 fire bow\n(3 end game";
        cin >> choice;

        if (choice == 1)
        {
            bow1.Draw();
        }
        else if (choice == 2)
        {
            bow1.Fire();
        }
        else
        {
            endgame = true;
        }
    }
    while (choice > 0 || choice < 3 || endgame == true);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Basic logic. **Think** before reading my answer, you'll get it.

Comment: Infinite loops don't end.

Comment: In addition to the other answers, you want to loop while choice > 0 *and* choice < 3, not *or*

Comment: it's bad practice to compare booleans with `true` or `false`. You should only use logical operations with booleans. (and, not, or, exclusive or)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
do {
    if (exit_condition)
        endgame = true;
} while (endgame == true);
```

This will set `endgame` to true when the exit condition is met, then loop back, because you check for `endgame` being **true** and not false. You want

```
} while (!endgame);
```

instead.

Comment: @Benjamin: As a useful tip, try to read it out loud to make sure it makes sense. In this case, `do{ /* ... something ... */ } while (!endgame);` should really be read like "do something while the game is not ended", which makes perfect sense. (and inside the loop, `if(condition) endgame = true;` should be read "if the condition occurs, end the game" )

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using **OR** (`||`):

- If `0 < choice < 3`, the loop will obviously continue since both `choice > 0` and `choice < 3` are true, this is what we want.
- However, if `choice >= 3` (say 10), the loop will continue since `choice > 0` is true
- and if `choice <= 0` (say -1), the loop will continue since `choice < 3` is true.

Thus the loop will always continue for any value of `choice` (regardless of `endgame`'s value).

Also, the loop will **continue** (instead of stopping) while `endgame` is `true`, which is set as soon as `choice` is given a value of not 1 or 2.

If you make it **AND** (`&&`) and reverse the `endgame` check, it should work:

```
while (choice > 0 && choice < 3 && endgame == false);
```

But really the `choice > 0 && choice < 3 &&` is unnecessary since you're setting `endgame` once either of those conditions hold.

```
while (endgame == false);
```

This can be simplified to:

```
while (!endgame);
```

Comment: Your conclusion after the bulleted list is correct, *but* the examples in the bulleted list are not good enough (they don't account for `choice` being 2, for example).

Comment: this is useful thank you, I would vote up this answer but my reputation is to low :(

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
if(endgame) break;
```

Try putting that at the end of your loop.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to stay in the loop as long as your `endgame` is false, so you only need to change your test in the while statement like this:

```
while (choice > 0 || choice < 3 || endgame == false)
```